# Java. GUI WindowBuilder scroll bar in text area doesn't work

Tags: java, class, user-interface, textarea, scrollbar

I don't know why my scroll bar in text area doesn't work. I found many solutions in internet, but no 1 helped for me.

```
textArea1 = new JTextArea();
textArea1.setBounds(13, 28, 182, 199);
panel.add(textArea1);

JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar();
scrollBar.setBounds(205, 1, 17, 242);
panel.add(scrollBar);
```

I found that can't be Panel's layout Absolute, if I change It to Group layout the same.
What's wrong? Could you help me? Thank you.

UPDATED:

```
package lt.kvk.i3_2.kalasnikovas_stanislovas;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.DropMode;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.Box;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;

public class KDVizualizuotas {

    private JFrame frmInformacijaApieMuzikos;
    private JTextField txtStilius;
    private JTextArea textArea1;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    KDVizualizuotas window = new KDVizualizuotas();
                    window.frmInformacijaApieMuzikos.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public KDVizualizuotas() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmInformacijaApieMuzikos = new JFrame();
        frmInformacijaApieMuzikos.setResizable(false);
        frmInformacijaApieMuzikos.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(KDVizualizuotas.class.getResource("/lt/kvk/i3_2/kalasnikovas_stanislovas/resources/Sidebar-Music-Blue-icon.png")));
        frmInformacijaApieMuzikos.setTitle("Muzikos stiliai");
        frmInformacijaApieMuzikos.setBounds(100, 100, 262, 368);
        frmInformacijaApieMuzikos.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        txtStilius = new JTextField();
        txtStilius.setBounds(10, 34, 128, 20);
        txtStilius.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnIekoti = new JButton("Ie\u0161koti");
        btnIekoti.setBounds(146, 36, 89, 19);
        btnIekoti.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        //      textArea1.append(txtStilius.getText()+"\n");
        //      txtStilius.getText();



                 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                    try {
                        FileReader fr = new FileReader("src/lt/kvk/i3_2/kalasnikovas_stanislovas/Stiliai.txt");
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                        String stiliuSarasas;
                        while((stiliuSarasas = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(stiliuSarasas);
                            textArea1.append(stiliuSarasas+"\n");
                            }
                        fr.close();
                        }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Error:" + e.toString());
                    }





            }
        });

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(10, 65, 224, 243);
        panel.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, null, null));
        panel.setBackground(SystemColor.text);

        JLabel lblveskiteMuzikosStili = new JLabel("\u012Eveskite muzikos stili\u0173:");
        lblveskiteMuzikosStili.setBounds(10, 14, 222, 14);
        frmInformacijaApieMuzikos.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        frmInformacijaApieMuzikos.getContentPane().add(panel);


        JLabel lblInformacijaApieMuzikos = new JLabel("Informacija apie muzikos stili\u0173:");
        lblInformacijaApieMuzikos.setBounds(12, 3, 190, 14);
        panel.add(lblInformacijaApieMuzikos);

        textArea1 = new JTextArea();
        textArea1.setBounds(13, 28, 182, 199);
        panel.add(textArea1);

        JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar();
        scrollBar.setBounds(205, 1, 17, 242);
        panel.add(scrollBar);
        frmInformacijaApieMuzikos.getContentPane().add(txtStilius);
        frmInformacijaApieMuzikos.getContentPane().add(btnIekoti);
        frmInformacijaApieMuzikos.getContentPane().add(lblveskiteMuzikosStili);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frmInformacijaApieMuzikos.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(mnFile);

        JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        mntmExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.exit(0);             
            }

        });
        mntmExit.setIcon(new ImageIcon(KDVizualizuotas.class.getResource("/lt/kvk/i3_2/kalasnikovas_stanislovas/resources/exitas.png")));
        mnFile.add(mntmExit);

        JMenu mnEdit = new JMenu("Edit");
        menuBar.add(mnEdit);

        JMenu mnHelp = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(mnHelp);

        JMenuItem mntmHelp = new JMenuItem("Help");
        mnHelp.add(mntmHelp);

        JMenu mnAbout = new JMenu("About");
        menuBar.add(mnAbout);

        JMenuItem mntmAbout = new JMenuItem("About");
        mntmAbout.setIcon(new ImageIcon(KDVizualizuotas.class.getResource("/lt/kvk/i3_2/kalasnikovas_stanislovas/resources/questionmark.png")));
        mnAbout.add(mntmAbout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try setting the text area as the scroll bars view `JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar(textArea1)` and don't use `null` layouts ;)

Comment: I tried that, but I got error: `The constructor JScrollBar(JTextArea) is undefined.` and what you mean "don't use null layouts"? Thank you for support.

Comment: A `null` layout means you're not using a layout manager, AKA absolute layout or absolute positioning.  Having to use `setBounds` is a good indication of an null/absolute layout - This is problematic and not recommended.  I'd need to see the code before I could diagnose the error

Comment: I updated my first post with full code.

Comment: This `setLayout(null)` is never recommended.  Also, the original problem persists, `JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar()` needs to be `JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar(textArea1)` and you don't need `panel.add(textArea1)`

Comment: As I said before, when I use `JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar(textArea1)` I got error: `The constructor JScrollBar(JTextArea) is undefined.`

Comment: Sorry, I completly missed the fact that you are trying to use a `JScrollBar` and not a `JScrollPane` :P - You don't need to do this you're self, this is what `JScrollPane` was designed for. Take a look at [How to use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Comment: I really not understand how to use ScrollPane, here are so much work to do that? Could you show me how ScrollPane must look in my code, please. Thank you very much.

Comment: Check the link in my previous comment - also check the updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the component you want to be contained within the scroll pane to it.

You can do this via the `JScrollPane`'s constructor or `JScrollPane#setViewportView` method

[image]

```
public class ScrollPaneTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ScrollPaneTest();
  }

  public ScrollPaneTest() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        JPanel bigPane = new JPanel();
        bigPane.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        // This is not recommended, but is used for demonstration purposes
        bigPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 768)); 

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(bigPane);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Updated with proper layout**

You should avoid `null` or absolute layouts, they will only hurt you in the long wrong.

You may also find [How to use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) of use

[image]

```
public class BadLayout {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new BadLayout();
  }

  public BadLayout() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TestPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

      }
    });
  }

  public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private JTextField searchField;
    private JButton searchButton;
    private JTextArea searchResults;

    public TestPane() {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      searchResults = new JTextArea();
      searchResults.setLineWrap(true);
      searchResults.setWrapStyleWord(true);
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(searchResults);

      JPanel results = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      results.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 8, 8, 8));
      results.add(scrollPane);
      add(results);

      JPanel search = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
      search.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 4, 8));
      searchField = new JTextField(12);
      searchButton = new JButton("Search");

      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      gbc.weightx = 1;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 4);
      search.add(searchField, gbc);

      gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
      gbc.gridx++;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
      gbc.weightx = 0;
      search.add(searchButton, gbc);

      add(search, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(200, 400);
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: I updated my first post with full code, may you explain how to use your code together with mine, what exactly I need to change?

Comment: The scroll bars won't become visible until the content extends beyond the size of the scroll pane, that's how it works.  If you REALLY want to see them (when there is nothing to scroll), use [`JScrollBar#setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setVerticalScrollBarPolicy%28int%29) and pass it a value of `ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS`

Comment: But how to make It in the same window? Is It possible? I don't need to open new frame.

Comment: Add it like other component. Remember, JScrollPane is just another container

Comment: Thank you for answers, I successfuly added JScrollPane from "Design" tab.